# Cannot disable directional arrows of my previous location

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

If i am at location 1 and hit it,after the delay of 10 sec arrows to the location 3 generates.
Now I move to location 3, when I hit location 3, Arrows generated by location 2 should turn off.

I tried hard to get my Deactivate previous function working but failed. Can anybody help regarding this?

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour {

public int _currentCheckPoint = 0;
public ArrowObjects _arrowObjectInstance;
public float _checkPointWaiTime = 10;
public float _elappsedTime;
public bool GenerateArrow = false;

    void Start()
    {
            _arrowObjectInstance = GetComponent<ArrowObjects> ();
            foreach (var item in _arrowObjectInstance._listArrowGameObject) {
                    item.SetActive (false);
            }
    }

    void Update()
    {

    if (_currentCheckPoint != 0 && GenerateArrow) {
        GenerateArrow = false;
        Invoke ("DelayedActive", 10f);

        }
    print (_currentCheckPoint);
    }

void DelayedActive()
{
    _arrowObjectInstance._listArrowGameObject [_currentCheckPoint - 1].SetActive (true);

}

void DeactivePrevious()
{
    _arrowObjectInstance._listArrowGameObject [_currentCheckPoint - 1].SetActive (false);
}


}
```

Comment: I'm going to have to see your ArrowObject class in order to help you.

Comment: Do you call DeactivatePrevious() just before calling the DelayedActive() method through Invoke ? If so, what problem is exactly happening when DeactivePrevious is called ? Also, i assume that ArrowObject class inherits from GameObject, right ?

Comment: I wsa previosuly calling the StartCoroutine ("DeactiveArrow"); in delayedActive which was working fine fr me.

IEnumerator DeactiveArrow()
 {
  yield return new WaitForSeconds(7);
  _arrowObjectInstance._listArrowGameObject [_currentCheckPoint - 1].SetActive (false);
 }

//---------
public GameObject[] _listArrowGameObject;
 yap declared this in Arrowobject.cs

Comment: @UriPopv I made a GameObject in it

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ArrowObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
  public GameObject[] _listArrowGameObject;
}

Comment: @RationalGaze I havent called DeactivePrevious() by invoke yet,I just want to turn off the arrows of my previous location.

Comment: Where do you call `DeactivePrevious`?

Comment: @MaryamBakhtawar this is what i don't understand. Just call DeactivePrevious() before the Invoke() in your update loop.

Comment: @GunnarB. I havent called it yet,I guess it should b called in DelayedActive().AM i right?

I was previously using the IEnumerator method

Comment: Well, it can't deactivate stuff it it is not called. You need to call it at a point where your indexing is correct. The lines from `DelayedActive` and `DeactivePrevious` are the same (->`[_currentCheckPoint - 1]`) so if you call them right after another without changing `_currentCheckPoint` in between they will access the same element.

Comment: @RationalGaze its not working.I called it above Invoke.Arrows frm the previous location doesnt turn off

Comment: @GunnarB. its because when i hit location 3 my currentCheckPoint chnaged to 3, 3-1=2 it should turn off the arrows of 2 location

Comment: It sure will, if you call it at that point. If you call it in `DelayedActive` it will be either executed exactly before or after that line (depending on if you put the call before or after the `SetActive(true)`. This means there will most likely not happen anything in betwenn and therefore both lines will effect the same index. Point is, I don't know your further code so I can't tell what the right point for calling that function is.

Comment: @GunnarB. that print  line in my code gives me the current position,i tested it,my current location is 3,i called my deactivate previous after the print line.it gave me an exeception of arry out of index but sorted it out with this check if (_currentCheckPoint != 0 && GenerateArrow)...

With that courtine methid i was using,this same line of code was working perfectly.it ws turning off after a delay of 7 secs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the update part from the above script to this.

```
void Update()
    {

    if (_currentCheckPoint != 0 && GenerateArrow) {
        GenerateArrow = false;
        if (_currentCheckPoint > 1) {
            _arrowObjectInstance._listArrowGameObject [_currentCheckPoint - 2].SetActive (false);
        }
        Invoke ("DelayedActive", 10f);


        }
```

and added a check in